# Android use Icepick library to save/restore bundle

Tags: android, parceler

I'm trying to use `Icepick` library on our application to save and restore bundle on phone rotation, but the library documentation i cant find good tips to save and classes which implemented by `@Parcel` annotation, this is simple class which i found o the page

`Example` class:

```
@Parcel
public class Example {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Example(){ /*Required empty bean constructor*/ }

    public Example(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public String setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int setAge(int age ) { this.age = age; }
}
```

`ExampleBundler` class:

```
public class ExampleBundler implements Bundler<Object> {
    @Override
    public void put(String s, Object example, Bundle bundle) {
        bundle.putParcelable(s, Parcels.wrap(example));
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String s, Bundle bundle) {
        return Parcels.unwrap(bundle.getParcelable(s));
    }
}
```

Ok, now how can i use that on `Activity` ?

this is my simple code which i try to save and restore

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

  /* @State(ExampleBundler.class) String message; */

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Example example = new Example();
    example.setName = "HELLO WORLD";
    example.setAge = 99;
  }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
    }
}
```

could you fix my code? Thank to advance

Comment: You also need to call `Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState)` in onCreate and  `Icepick.saveInstanceState(this,outstate)` in the onSaveInstanceState

Comment: @SahithReddy and how can i fox this line: `@State(ExampleBundler.class) String message;`

Comment: If it is just a string you do not even need the custom bundler you can just use @State. custom bundler is if you want to save a whole object in conjunction with parcelable

Comment: @SahithReddy this is String, but its wrong and i must fix that, `@state` must be as Parcel or other type. i dont know

Comment: ok sorry I understand the problem. First, I think you should `ExampleBundler implements Bundler<Object>` should be `ExampleBundler implements Bundler<Example>`. So then in the overrided methods you can use the Example object instead of the general Object. Then, add this `@State(ExampleBundler.class) Example example;` instead of the comment you have. Finally, add the first comment i posted about Icepick restore and save. If you want more detail I can post an actual answer instead of comments.

Comment: @SahithReddy ok, i understand me sir, thanks, can you post answer and let me to accept that? if i have problem i can post comment under your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your code, the bundler has to implement the example class not the general object class so change

```
    public class ExampleBundler implements Bundler<Object> {
    @Override
    public void put(String s, Object example, Bundle bundle) {
        bundle.putParcelable(s, Parcels.wrap(example));
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String s, Bundle bundle) {
        return Parcels.unwrap(bundle.getParcelable(s));
    }
}
```

to this

```
public class ExampleBundler implements Bundler<Example> {
    @Override
    public void put(String s, Example example, Bundle bundle) {
        bundle.putParcelable(s, Parcels.wrap(example));
    }

    @Override
    public Example get(String s, Bundle bundle) {
        return Parcels.unwrap(bundle.getParcelable(s));
    }
}
```

Then, you have to add `@State(ExampleBundler.class) Example example;` to the top of your activity. In your onCreate add `Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState)` and in your onSavedInstanceState add `Icepick.saveInstanceState(this,outstate)`

[Icepick documentation](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick) and [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)